# Accumuler ou Cumuler ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, verbes, synonymes

J'ai cru comprendre qu'accumuler et cumuler sont des termes français d'origine latine tous deux acceptés.

Toutefois, la différence entre les deux semble mince et je voulais savoir :

À quel moment doit-on utiliser **cumuler** plutôt qu' **accumuler** ?

Dans le cas particulier d'une (enfin, plusieurs) dettes. Dois-je écrire :

> Il cumulait les dettes.

ou

> Il accumulait les dettes.

Si vous avez d'autres exemples, merci de les partager !

Comment: Dans ce cas précis, je pencherais plutôt pour _cumuler des dettes_ et à l'inverse pour _accumuler des avoirs_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La frontière est assez floue.

### En général

D'après le [dictionnaire Larousse sur un post Facebook](https://fr-fr.facebook.com/larousse.fr/posts/393264590737691):

> On peut donc simplifier en disant que **accumuler** des choses, c’est les empiler littéralement ou au figuré et **cumuler** des choses, c’est les avoir toutes à un même moment.

On dirait:

> Il **cumule** les mandats.

Mais:

> Il **accumule** les cadavres dans son placard.

En français, le préfixe **ac** fait passer une idée d'aggrégation, de rapprochement de plusieurs éléments.

### Dans ton cas

On va pas se mentir, c'est un peu compliqué : on peut considérer que les dettes sont associées à la personne et la suivent partout, auquel cas **cumuler** a du sens.

Mais on peut aussi considérer qu'une dette est un bout de papier sur lequel il est écrit que tu dois de l'argent, auquel cas l'action de les **accumuler** figurativement dans un coin de ton bureau n'est pas non plus dénuée de sens.

Pour ce que ça vaut, [Google Trends](https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=cumuler%20%2B%20dettes%2C%20accumuler%20%2B%20dettes&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT-2) donne "cumuler + dettes" et "accumuler + dettes" très serrés, avec un léger avantager pour cumuler.

+1 pour la question dans tous les cas.

Comment: J'ai l'impression que dans "accumuler" il y a en effet une notion de faire un stock (comme tu dis, dans un placard par exemple), qu'il n'y a pas dans "cumuler"

Comment: Tu dis cumuler c'est avoir tout en même temps. Mais alors ton exemple avec les cadavres, tu ne les as pas justement tous en même temps dans ton placard? Selon tes explications, j'aurais tendance à pencher pour *cumuler* les dettes. Je vais attendre de voir les autres réponses.

Comment: **Cumuler** a, selon moi, une notion importante de **sur sa personne** illustrée dans [les deux premiers cas ici](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/cumuler/21091?q=cumuler#20969). C'est pas simplement réunir des éléments, mais les avoir sur sa personne comme des mandats, des diplômes, des titres de noblesse. Et je pense que les dettes peuvent en effet en faire partie.

Comment: @MadWard D'où je viens (Canada), les dettes sont associé à ton numéro d'assurance social. Un numéro unique qui permet au gouvernement (et banques, etc.) de t'identifier. J'estime donc qu'effectivement, les dettes sont liés à la personne et utiliserait le terme cumuler. Il cumule les dettes quand on veut dire qu'il en a une pour son automobile, sa maison, son crédit. Et on dirait qu'il accumule les dettes quand on veut dire qu'il doit par exemple 200'000$ en plus encore..?

Answer (score 3):

C'est assez subtil parce que la plupart des usages sont interchangeables sans grande différence de sens, mais on peut y voir plus clair en regardant des cas où les deux mots ne sont pas interchangeables.

On dit par exemple : *cumuler des mandats*, *cumuler des fonctions*, et non *accumuler*.

On dit aussi *l'écureuil accumule des noisettes*, et non *cumule*.

Par ces exemples, on voit que la notion d'*accumulation* se rapporte à la constitution progressive, par petits morceaux, d'une grande quantité de quelque chose. *Accumuler* correspond à cet usage.

Par contraste, le *cumul* se rapporte à la détention, la consommation, l'exécution (...) simultanée de plusieurs choses. *Il cumule les petites amies* (il en a plusieurs en ce moment, mais il n'en constitue pas pour autant une réserve), *il cumule l'alcool et le tabac*, *il cumule les fonctions de cuistot et de balayeur*.

Pour la question spécifique des dettes, il y a une très légère différence de sens ou plutôt d'emphase. *Accumuler les dettes* signifie s'endetter beaucoup, au fil du temps, petit à petit. *Cumuler les dettes* signifie qu'à l'instant présent, le sujet a plusieurs dettes, sans forcément se référer à la croissance du nombre de ces dettes au fil du temps (même si c'est assez probable que le cumul résulte d'une accumulation ai fil du temps).

Comment: Belle réponse, il est pertinent de faire la différence entre cumuler et accumuler au sein du même exemple (les dettes).

Answer (score 2):

D'après le Larousse :

> Accumuler : *Faire, avoir, etc., des choses (abstraites) en grand nombre*

Ce terme s'emploie surtout pour les choses abstraites. De manière générale, je dirais que son emploi dans la langue est surtout présent pour **évoquer du passif**.

> Cumuler : *Ajouter quelque chose à quelque chose d'autre en formant un ensemble excessif*

Contrairement au précédent, je dirais que l'emploi de cumuler sert surtout à évoquer l'actif, ou encore **des éléments sur lesquels on a le contrôle**.

Dans ton cas, la formulation

> Il **accumulait** les dettes

laisse à penser qu'il ne pouvait pas faire grand-chose pour éviter ça. En revanche

> Il **cumulait** les dettes

suggère qu'il connaissait effectivement la provenance des dettes qu'il cumulait et qu'il en était le dépositaire.

Cela dit, la frontière reste floue.

Comment: Je ne pense pas que le fait qu'il connaisse l'origine des dettes ait une importance. Quand je parle à mon comptable et lui dit *il (ac)cumulait les dettes*, je ne sais même pas moi-même si *il* connaissait l'origine des dettes ou non, s'il avait le contrôle.

Comment: @Carlos2W Très juste. Dans le cas de ton comptable, ce n'est pas tant l'origine des dettes qui sera importante, mais plutôt sa part de responsabilité. Dans le français d'aujourd'hui, dire : il _cumulait_ les dettes implique plus de responsabilité pour le comptable que la formulation : il _accumulait_ . J'imagine que mon analyse s'appuie plus ou moins sur les équivalent avec le préfixe **a** . Example : les ordures s'**a**moncelaient , les particules s'**a**ggrègent... Dans ces cas-là, personne n'est vraiment responsable, les choses se font (passif me voilà).